# how to store json response without name for value to listview in android?

Tags: android, json, listview, post, response

I need to store the Json Response to list view.

I got the response from server like this.

```
["100","name","Test","1234","2017-03-22 14:07:19.0","Project Name"]
```

But the common format for JSON is like

```
{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" };
```

So we can able to get the details by

```
detail.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
detail.setCity(jRealObject.getString("city"));
```

So my question is, How can I get the value and store it in listview for the response like this?
    ["100","name","Test","1234","2017-03-22 14:07:19.0","Project Name"]

Comment: this should be fixed on the server side to return json object

Comment: otherwise you have to rely on the position of each element in the array which IMO is not a good design at all.

Comment: Thanks @mihail . Can you share the code how to store a value in different textview in custom listview?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a `JsonArray`

To extract data from this we do:

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
        String string = array.getString(i);
        //Do something with string
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But in My case, I need to store each value in different textview in Custom list view. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    try {
        ArrayList<String> list_service = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray itemArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
            String value=itemArray.getString(i);
            Log.e("json","Value :"+value);
            list_service.add(value);
        }

        //set custom adapter
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. @user2025187 But in My case, I need to store each value in different textview in Custom list view. Is it possible?

Comment: @paul check updated code.Save your response in ArrayList and set to your custom list

Answer (score 1):

JSON is built on two structures:

1. A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
2. An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence. for more information
   http://www.json.org/

In your questions the first one is JSONObject and last one is JSONArray. Yor example data can be parsed into a list using following code:

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray j = new JSONArray("[\"100\",\"name\",\"Test\",\"1234\",\"2017-03-22 14:07:19.0\",\"Project Name\"]");
            for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++){
                list.add((String)j.get(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc){}
```

For ListView: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
              http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Example of ListView to store json parsed data:

Add a custom adapter to for listview

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> values;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
        super(context, -1, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row, parent, false);//R.layout.list_view_row is your custom list row template
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        textView.setText(values.get(position));
        // change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        String s = values.get(position);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Add list_view_row.xml in yor lauout file and add following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your MainActivity.java:

```
ListView listView;
    TextView textView;
    List <String> jsonList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ReadJson();
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ReadJson();
        CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, jsonList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void ReadJson(){
        jsonList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray j = new JSONArray("[\"100\",\"name\",\"Test\",\"1234\",\"2017-03-22 14:07:19.0\",\"Project Name\"]");
            for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++){
                jsonList.add((String)j.get(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc){}
    }
    public void broadcastIntent(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

My activity_main.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nargis.alarmreceiver.MainActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks @user7676575. Can you explain how can I store the each value in different TextView in my Custom listview?

Comment: @paul check updated code.Save your response in ArrayList and set to your custom list